# Redirect router on after login

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to figure out how to redirect my react app to proper page after it has been authenticated through the login.

Here is my App.js file with the routed (without imports):

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}  />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" render={() => <h1>Welcome</h1>} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am using PrivateRoute component to make sure private routes get authenticated:

```
class PrivateRoute extends Route {
render() {
    const { component: Component, isAuthenticated } = this.props;

    let propsCopy = Object.assign({}, this.props);
    delete propsCopy.component;
    delete propsCopy.isAuthenticated;
    return (
        isAuthenticated
        ? <Component {...propsCopy} />
        : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: LOGIN_PATH,
            state: { from: this.props.location }
        }} />
    );
}
}

/**
 * Maps properties from Redux store to this component.
 * @param {Object} state Redux object
 * @return {Object} mapper properties
 */
function mapStateToProps(state) {
// pull out auth element from Redux store state
const { auth } = state;
// extract authenticated element from auth object
const { isAuthenticated } = auth;

return {
    isAuthenticated
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

My Login component that get redirected to (simplified for the sake of the example:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();


        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }

        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);


    }


    handleFormSubmit(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();

        const validation = this.validator.validate(this.state);
        this.setState({ validation });
        this.submitted = true;

        if (validation.isValid) {
            // submit form here
            this.props.loginUser({
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                });
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (

            // My login FROM code here
        )

    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isFetching: state.auth.isFetching,
        loginError: state.auth.loginError,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props, state) {
    return {
        loginUser: (credentials) => {
            dispatch(loginUser(credentials));
        },
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Right now it works where it redirects to the `LoginForm` component if `isAuthenticated` is false. I can submit the login form to my login service and receive a success response and set `isAuthenticated`.

My question is how to I redirect to the original route? Where is redirection normally done? I'm assuming it's never done in the reducer so it would have to be done in the `LoginForm` component right?

I know there are a lot of resources discuss this whole login flow but I can't find one that deals with this issue(which surprised me). Everyone redirects to a specific page ('/', '/home' etc) but how do i capture and redirect to the original route.

Comment: Why're you using redux for authentication ?

Comment: Do you need this data elsewhere ?

Comment: Probably so that they can access authentication status effectively anywhere in the application.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor alexander is spot on. We want to check authentication though out the app.

Comment: There's a big IF there. I see. Unless it becomes necessity

Comment: you're getting refreshToken in response that you're sending in header of all APIs further. ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor haven't fully implemented but yes that is the plan.

Comment: bos@570 I appreciate it. I'm writing a detailed explanation in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrivateRoute` component is storing the previous route in `from` when a redirect occurs due to `isAuthenticated` being `false`. This can be used in `LoginForm` to redirect the user when `isAuthenticated` is `true`. Just extract `from` from `this.props.location.state` and use that in combination with `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`. If you log `this.props.location.state.from` you will see the property `pathname` containing the string route path that the user attempted to get to in an unauthenticated state, which can be used to redirect them once authentication is successful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const validation = this.validator.validate(this.state);
    this.setState({ validation });
    this.submitted = true;

    if (validation.isValid) {
      // submit form here
      this.props.loginUser({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to={from} />;
    }

    return (
      {* login from code *}
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetching: state.auth.isFetching,
    loginError: state.auth.loginError,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props, state) {
  return {
    loginUser: (credentials) => {
      dispatch(loginUser(credentials));
    },
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm));
```

You may need to update your `PrivateRoute` component is well to ensure it returns a `Route`, this would be in line with `react-router-dom` [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props =>
    rest.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: LOGIN_PATH,
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
  />
);    

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated } }) => ({ isAuthenticated });

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute));
```

I've created a simplified [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgbxad) demonstrating the functionality in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: ahh, that def makes sense. I do get an error here though..`this.props.location.state` comes through as undefined. I don't know how I would access the from prop.

Comment: You would need to probably add `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` to help with that issue as this is a connected component. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think there may be an issue with your `PrivateRoute`. It should be returning a `Route`.

Comment: Your initial solution to the problem works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean alex?

Comment: If you look at the auth example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow, `PrivateRoute` is returning `Route` with a `render` function. This would make sense as when not using a `PrivateRoute` you would be using `Route`.  In the authenticated case in your `PrivateRoute` you aren't returning a `Route`, but simply the component, this could cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Helped me expedite my learning process by hours.

Comment: So, `this.props.location` still is undefined and I can't figure out why? Honestly I can't see how it's getting passed to the props int the first place

Comment: `this.props.location` is populated by `react-router-dom` when using a `Route`. Did you update the `PrivateRoute` to return a `Route` with a render function similar to the official example?

Comment: yeah, still is undefined unfotuntately.

Comment: I've made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgbxad) to demonstrate the functionality. Hopefully that can help pinpoint the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You! was missing the `withRouter` bit. You've been alot of help.

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander and @bos570 first of all I really appreciate the way you've done this. There are better approaches to this but here is an implementation to build it in controlled way:

In your `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './styles.scss'; // it depends what styles you're using css,scss,jss
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In your `App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
  };

componentDidMount(){
//call authentication API here
// setState isAuthentication to true upon authentication success

}

render(){
return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>{isAuthenticated ? <Routes /> : <Login />}</BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
)}
```

Your `Routes.js` will have all routes in a `Switch` and It will keep showing loading screen unless API response gives success. and you re-route to a basic Login page.

Even If you've done code splitting It would not download any bundles from network except main.bundle.js upon authentication failure. 
I see people when people use `Redux` like jack of all trades in programming. I know you future implementation for  authentication will give you an refreshToken that's what Authentication API does for us. You can store it in localStorage and You need to do this if someone refresh the browser at any instant you can't keep it in redux as we know redux will lose state upon browser refresh so here **localStorage** comes into the play. Use it wisely I would really like to have conversion with both of you how can we make it more better.

I hope this would be helpful for you. and Maybe redux will be used side by side for Authentication. I have had a great time while implementing auth in an app.
Cheers

**EDITED** keep it as it you've done. But we need to know at which point, you need **redux, localStorage, Context API**

Comment: How in your example would you be able to keep track of which path the user came from when unauthenticated so that upon successful authentication they can be redirected to that desired path instead of a hard coded path? This is what the requester was asking.

Comment: App component is parent component of all routes, It will be mounted once. Upon authentication you could get into the real app and keep track of every thing with react-router

Comment: You won't need authentication again and again on each route.. If you put /x/y/z in browser directly. You first component would be App.js

Comment: Sure, but you should show that specifically in your answer. The authentication state can change depending on a number of situations. The user can be redirected to `LOGIN_PATH` from effectively any path and would need to be sent back to that path specifically. Show how to track and use `/x/y/z` across varying paths and varying states with your suggested structure. There is nothing wrong with not using Redux as you suggested, but you aren't answering the specific question of the requester.

Comment: Yes you're right I just gave a little explanation. We can make it's implementation in one of the main route in  our routes and check history prop path name as we are in BrowserRouter to where should be redirect user

Comment: Further if we write `/x/y/z/` It will still keep the path-name  and authenticate the user. Upon AUTH success `BrowserRouter` will do the work for us